# Why does matplotlib write out ~100K temp files every day

Tags: matplotlib

For some reason matplotlib writes over 100K temp directories on a daily basis to /tmp/ on our server and we cannot figure out why. Each of the directories just contains one file, named 'fontlist-v330.json', which has a bunch of font info in in.

Does anyone know why it does this and how to make it stop?

Some environment info:

matplotlib version: 3.3.4
python version: 3.6
OS: ubuntu 18.04

Update: when we upgraded matplotlib to version 3.5.1 this problem went away.

Comment: Maybe [issue 13071](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13071) is relevant here? Did you consider upgrading matplotlib?

Answer (score 0):

Update: when we upgraded matplotlib to version 3.5.1 this problem went away.